# How retain the multi line string from python to html

Tags: python, html, flask

I am sending a multiline string from python to HTML, in HTML when i use this string variable to print, its printing as single string.

Python code :

```
@app.route("/<faqid>")
@is_logged_in
def faqid(faqid):`enter code here`
    device = """
     class-map match-any eftv6-bun-1
      match access-group ipv6 eftv6-bun 
       end-class-map
      !

    policy-map qp-80 
    class eftv6-bun-1
    set dscp af31
    ! 
    class class-default
    ! 
   end-policy-map
  ! 
     """
    return render_template("faqdetails.html", device=device)
```

HTML faqdetails.html

```
<div style="b`enter code here`ackground-color:white;">
    <p style="text-align:left;"> {{device}} </p>
</div>
```

in web page faqdetails.html this is showing as

> "class-map match-any eftv6-bun-1 match access-group ipv6 eftv6-bun end-class-map ! policy-map qp-80 class eftv6-bun-1 set dscp af31 ! class class-default ! end-policy-map !"

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace newline with `<br>` tags.

You might get away with something like `device = device.replace("\n", "<br>")`.

Alternatively, this seems to be a good snippet for making a custom Flask filter:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/

Just put that somewhere and register it according to these instructions:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#custom-filters

After that, in your template you should be able to write
`{{ device|nl2br }}`

Answer (score 0):

Below HTML code helped

```
<div style="background-color:white;">
            <!--<p style="text-align: left font-family:bold;">Answer:</p> 
<br>-->
           {%  set ans = device.split("\n")%}
           {% for answ in ans%}
                <p style="text-align: left; font-family: normal; font-size: 
 16px;"> {{ answ  }} </p>
           {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Or

wrap the output in pre  tags.. it should preserve the formatting of the string as below below

```
<div style="background-color:white;">
            <!--<p style="text-align: left font-family:bold;">Answer:</p> 
          <br>-->
        <pre style="text-align: left; font-family: normal; font- 
        size: 16px; background-color:white;"> {{ device  }} </pre>
    </div>
```